# How to make Python HTTP server have custom url instead of localhost?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, networking, httpserver

I'm using the HTTP server module in Python 3 and I want to make my local HTTP server have a custom url instead of "localhost:8080". Is there any way for me to do this in Python alone without changing default OS settings like the settings in the host file?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please clarify what you mean by a 'custom url'?  Do you have any code to explain your setup?

Answer (score 0):

When you can setup your router, you must make a port-forwarding. (You usually can setup it on http://192.168.0.1/)

Then you can use that url: "http:// Your Global IP:8080/" for example, when my global IP address is 4.4.0.0, than "http://4.4.0.0:8080/".

When you use the port 80 instead of 8080 (you can setup in port forwarding), it is the professional port of http server, your url will be (with the last example ip): "http://4.4.0.0/"

You can see your global IP address for example on this page: https://whatismyipaddress.com/

or from python code:

```
gloval_IP = get('https://api.ipify.org').text
```